# General properties of an optimal solution of a convex program

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How do we seek certain properties for a solution of a convex minimization problem.
For example we want to make sure if the below objective has a symmetric optimal solution:

\begin{equation}
\min_X f(X) \text{ s.t. } X1=1,  X\ge 0
\end{equation}

for some convex function $f$.

My question is about the general steps one should take for such a goal.